# I need to make a loop that creates different lists with the str that it takes

Tags: python, string, list, loops

iterate a story and now the fragments through a loop, create individual lists of each one

this is what I have of code:

```
en_story = str("""It was a dark and moonless night. Enough light shone from the porch light to show the broken coat hanger that stuck out of the porch stair rail. Lily sighed and wrapped her shawl around her other arm, picking her way from the driveway to the porch.

She had known this day would come. It was inevitable, really. First her car had broken down, and then she'd lost her job. And now, here she was, returning to the one place she had sworn she would never set foot in again.

The key turned in the lock with a click, and Lily stepped into the musty-smelling house. It wasn't much, but it was home. She flicked on the light, revealing a dusty living room with peeling wallpaper and a sagging couch. Lily sighed and dropped her bags on the floor.

It was going to be a long night.""")
print(en_story)

en_sentence = [x for x in en_story.replace("\n","").split(".") if x != ""] 
print(en_sentence)
n=1

output=[en_sentence[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(en_sentence), n)]
print(output)
it = iter(output)

for i in it:
  print(i)



try something like this, but here I have to create the lists manually:

i_set = set(i)  

good, bad = [], []
for item in i:
    if item in i_set:
        good.append(item)
    else:
        bad.append(item)

print(good)
print(bad)
```

Comment: You'll need to define "different lists" more clearly.  It looks like the code maybe wants to sort the individual words into two lists called "good" and "bad", but I can't figure out how you actually want to determine "good" and "bad".

Comment: what I want to do is generate multiple empty lists in a loop and fill them with fragments of the story I create. the good and bad list is a part of the code that I tried to create for that but it did not turn out as expected